# How do I fix Notice message on my foreach

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

Here an example my wordpress meta box foreach.

```
foreach ($meta_box['fields'] as $field) {

        $old = get_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], true);
        $new = $_POST[$field['id']];

         if (isset($_POST[$field['id']])) {
            update_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $new);

        } elseif ('' == $new && $old) {
            delete_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $old);
        }
}
```

If here have empty input I'll got `Notice: Undefined index:` at `$new` How to fix this one?

Comment: Did you set the `$post_id` variable?

Comment: full code http://pastebin.com/HXDe0EjE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to test if the **$_POST[$field['id']]** is set before calling it, otherwise you'll trigger that error. You're checking for it on the next line, so just move it up.

```
foreach($meta_box['fields'] as $field){
    if(isset($_POST[$field['id']])){
        // POST field sent - update
        $new = $_POST[$field['id']];
        update_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $new);

    } else {
        // POST field not sent - delete
        $old = get_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], true);
        delete_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $old);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change `$new = $_POST[$field['id']];` to:

```
$new = ( IsSet ( $_POST[$field['id']] ) === true ? $_POST[$field['id']] : 'some default value' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Before init of $new you can check if it exists:

```
if(isset($_POST[$field['id']])) {
    $new = $_POST[$field['id']];
}
else {
    $new = "default";
}
```

If not exists you set it to the default value.

Comment: Why are you posting an answer that is exactly the same as the one already posted?

Comment: Because I submitted it without seeing there was one inserted already. Besides that, it is more clear to not write it in one line.